# How can I get pathname-expanded variable?

Tags: bash

all.

In bash's parameter syntax,

```
  name=val
```

`val` does not get pathname-expansion.

How can I put pathname-expanded result to another variable?

```
$ ls foo*
foo.1
$ A="foo.*"
$ echo $A
foo.1
$ touch foo.2
$ echo $A
foo.1 foo.2
```

I want to have `A` retain value `"foo.1"` after touching `foo.2`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array instead.

```
A=(foo.*)
touch foo.2
echo "${A[@]}"
```

Comment: Did you really mean `echo "${foo[@]}"`?

Comment: Thank you! for pointing me compound assignment... I first tried with `declare -a arr; arr=foo.*; ...`, not `arr=(foo.*)` :-(